# Python expressions in f-strings do not return same result as str() conversion for subclasses?

Tags: python, string, overriding, f-string

For example, we override the `__str__` method in `Decimal` then call it two different ways

```
from decimal import Decimal
class D(Decimal):
    def __str__(self):
        return super().normalize().__str__()
num = D('1.0')
print(f"{num}")
print(f"{str(num)}")
```

outputs

```
1.0
1
```

But they should both output `1`. It seems like the first `print` is calling `Decimal.__str__` instead of `D.__str__` for some reason. Why does this happen and how do I fix the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to override `__format__` too (see [the f-string PEP, search for `__format__`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#specification)).

```
from decimal import Decimal


class D(Decimal):
    def __str__(self):
        return super().normalize().__str__()

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return super().normalize().__format__(format_spec)


num = D('1.0')
print(f"{num}")
print(f"{str(num)}")
```

prints out

```
1
1
```